# Is it possible to have functions with multiple type signatures in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I apologize for this question. I've been away for a while and feel like I've forgotten everything I knew.

I want to do something like this.

```
data X = X 
data Y = Y

myEq X X = True
myEq Y Y = True
myEq _ _ = False
```

I've tried various declarations for `myEq`. I've also tried to define a type class that might do it. But nothing I could think of compiled.

Is something like this possible? And if so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: How would this function be used?

Comment: You are probably inventing http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Type-Equality.html

Comment: Or else `myEq :: (Typeable a, Typeable b, Eq b) => a -> b -> Bool` implemented with `myEq x y = maybe False (== y) (cast x)`. Of course, you'd have to then derive `Typeable` for everything.

Comment: A better question: What do you think you need this function for?

Comment: I am looking for a type whose instances are equal to each other and different from those of all other types. I know that doesn't explain why I want such a type, but that's too long for a comment -- and probably not interesting to most people in any case.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it.

```
data X = X deriving (Show)
data Y = Y deriving (Show)

class (Show a) => MyEquatable a 

instance MyEquatable X
instance MyEquatable Y

myEq :: (MyEquatable a, MyEquatable b) => a -> b -> Bool
myEq a b = show a == show b
```

Of course, if doesn't have to be `show`, but that's a simple way to do it.